# Kafka producer future metadata in callback

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

In my application when I send messages I use the Metadata in the callback to save the offset of the record for future usage. However sometimes the metadata.offset() returns -1 which makes things hard later.
Why does this happen and is there a way to get the offset without consuming the topic to find it.

Edit: I am on ack 0 currently, when I pass to ack 1 I don't have these errors anymore however my performance drops drastically. From 100k message in 10 sec to 1 min.

Answer (score 0):

> acks=0 If set to zero then the producer will not wait for any
>   acknowledgment from the server at all. The record will be immediately
>   added to the socket buffer and considered sent. No guarantee can be
>   made that the server has received the record in this case, and the
>   retries configuration will not take effect (as the client won't
>   generally know of any failures). **The offset given back for each
>   record will always be set to -1.**

This is not exactly true as out of 100k messages I got 95k with offsets but I guess it's normal.
Still will need to find another solution to get the offset with ack=0